# Deploying ganache-local w/brownie: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Tags: ganache, brownie

I am going through brownie_fund_me part of this course:

`https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/brownie_fund_me`

The initial deploy,.py works properly, but I keep getting some variation of invalid opcode and the transaction keeps reverting when I try to deploy to ganache-local. I am able to run the tests in this project to development/ganache-cli but fail with ganache-local and Rinkeby.

### Expected Behavior

Contract should deploy fund and withdraw properly with Ganache UI.

### Current Behavior

Running `brownie run deploy.py --network ganache-local. I get these errors while running or troubleshooting.

- ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
- ValueError: Execution reverted during call: 'execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, include `allow_revert:True` as a transaction parameter.
- VirtualMachineError: invalid opcode: invalid opcode

### Steps to reproduce & Troubleshooting

1. Git clone `https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/brownie_fund_me`
2. brownie compile -a.  Compiles successfully.

```
  Solc version: 0.6.12
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
Generating build data...
 - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/AggregatorInterface
 - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/AggregatorV2V3Interface
 - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/AggregatorV3Interface
 - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/SafeMathChainlink
 - FundMe
 - MockV3Aggregator
 Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at /Users/davidandrews/Documents/Projects/Web3/bss/build/contracts
```

2. Deploy ganache ui with default gas limit and values.
3. Execute `brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network ganache-local`

```
 ~/Documents/Projects/Web3/brownie_fund_me (main●●)$ brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network ganache-local 
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

brownie_fund_me is the active project.

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
The active network is ganache-local
Deploying Mocks...
Transaction sent: 0xe7b501480f70836256dbdd37a159100198d1422897117777e33588d1b2e1a566
  Gas price: 20.0 gwei   Gas limit: 540226   Nonce: 0
  MockV3Aggregator.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 491115 (90.91%)
  MockV3Aggregator deployed at: 0xF5F2B13A72901f1621d2CD9b382c1c513ac0724D

Mocks Deployed!
Transaction sent: 0xc5a26f42997e9c648ee4d12df1805746cd3ca6508c315747f9b836ce5fb39516
  Gas price: 20.0 gwei   Gas limit: 528696   Nonce: 1
  FundMe.constructor confirmed   Block: 2   Gas used: 480633 (90.91%)
  FundMe deployed at: 0xEDa314a434Ef759d85F60a54804FdfdbEB26F179

Contract deployed to 0xEDa314a434Ef759d85F60a54804FdfdbEB26F179
```

4. Execute:  `brownie run scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py --network ganache-local`

```
BssProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py::main'...
25000000000000000
The current entry fee is 25000000000000000
Funding
Transaction sent: 0xffd686e74b439f0afff97ba5ab77ce31a48a66a6f2710d123b3cf37bc8b8bade
  Gas price: 20.0 gwei   Gas limit: 94207   Nonce: 2
  FundMe.fund confirmed   Block: 3   Gas used: 85643 (90.91%)

  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py", line 23, in main
    withdraw()
  File "./scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py", line 18, in withdraw
    fund_me.withdraw({"from": account})
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1625, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1498, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 644, in transfer
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 727, in _make_transaction
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "brownie/exceptions.py", line 121, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

5. Change gas_limit param to default Ganache UI gas_limit: `fund_me.withdraw({"from": account})` -> `fund_me.withdraw({"from": account, 'gas_limit': 6721975})` and run `fund_and_withdraw.py.`

```
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BssProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py::main'...
25000000000000000
The current entry fee is 25000000000000000
Funding
Transaction sent: 0x996f97219b9c8cf1dd3f88753adf4c94335d27d1784972b976c550cea5f13c6d
  Gas price: 20.0 gwei   Gas limit: 61207   Nonce: 3
  FundMe.fund confirmed   Block: 4   Gas used: 55643 (90.91%)

  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py", line 24, in main
    withdraw()
  File "./scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py", line 19, in withdraw
    fund_me.withdraw({"from": account, 'gas_limit': 6721975})
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1625, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1498, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 644, in transfer
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 752, in _make_transaction
    exc = VirtualMachineError(e)
  File "brownie/exceptions.py", line 121, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Execution reverted during call: 'execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, include `allow_revert:True` as a transaction parameter.
```

6. Added `fund_me.withdraw({"from": account, 'gas_limit': 6721975, 'allow_revert': True})`

```
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py::main'...
25000000000000000
The current entry fee is 25000000000000000
Funding
Transaction sent: 0x1709a9bb9cf6213526c0307eb01c91c00a644a227c8a0efffa71310f3b94a106
  Gas price: 20.0 gwei   Gas limit: 61207   Nonce: 4
  FundMe.fund confirmed   Block: 5   Gas used: 55643 (90.91%)

  FundMe.fund confirmed   Block: 5   Gas used: 55643 (90.91%)

Transaction sent: 0x5e4947dc2d642dbb337eefdb6711c33b39eca70e2294aed10c05e3d15861b3a2
  Gas price: 20.0 gwei   Gas limit: 6721975   Nonce: 5
  FundMe.withdraw confirmed (invalid opcode)   Block: 6   Gas used: 6721975 (100.00%)

  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py", line 28, in main
    withdraw()
  File "./scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py", line 21, in withdraw
    tx = fund_me.withdraw({"from": account, 'gas_limit': 6721975, 'allow_revert': True})
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1625, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1498, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 682, in transfer
    receipt._raise_if_reverted(exc)
  File "brownie/network/transaction.py", line 446, in _raise_if_reverted
    raise exc._with_attr(
VirtualMachineError: invalid opcode: invalid opcode
```

6. I am also deleting build artifacts between runs.
7. I've tried this:

- delete ganache-local from your brownie networks list
- delete the corresponding folders on build/deployments/1337(or whatever your chainID was) as well as the corresponding chainid lines of the map.json file
- on your Ganache instance, instead of clicking on the quicklaunch, click on create workspace
- Set up the gas limit to a higher number than it is currently at (I chose 8000000), the rest can stay as it is
- on your VSC terminal, or whatever program you use to type your code, re-introduce the network ganache-local (brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-local host=http://YOURHOSTNUMBER chainid=YOURCHAINID

I've tried setting the gas_limit in ganache ui to 999999999999999 and gas price to gwei.

### Possible Solution

This appears to be a gas estimation and gas price issue with Ganache UI.

### Context

I'm trying to complete this course: `https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py#lesson-6-brownie-fund-me`

### Your Environment

- Python 3.9.8
- Ganache version: `Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)` RPC Server: `HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545 chainid=1377`
- Ganache UI version: `Version 2.5.4 (2.5.4.1367)`
- Node version: `v16.8.0`
- Operating System and version: `macOS Monterey 12.1 Beta`
- Truffle version: `Truffle v5.4.21`
- Link to your project: `https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/brownie_fund_me`. I've cloned this repo to make sure I didn't have a bug in my own code.

Comment: From the error message it doesn't seem to be an issue with the gas but the contract is reverting for some other reason.

Comment: I encountered the same error too. When I ran getPrice() on the FundMe contract, the answer returned was 200000000000,0000000000,0000000000. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

getPrice() isn't returning a number you want from the mock, somewhere in the vicinity of 2B. Think this is a bug with the Ganache implementation- performing the calculation (minimumUSD * precision) / price
in getEntranceFee() gives you a number less than 1- and, since Solidity can't handle floats, Solidity simply sees it as a 0, and the whole thing errors out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the version of Ganache:
If you use the ganache GUI, you get the miscalculation regarding the entree fee and gas estimation error.
If you start the ganache-cli locally, in another window, it works, both the calculation and the call of withdraw() :

> ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasPrice 2000000000 --gasLimit 6721975 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545

I am using ganache@7.0.3 installed from npm -g install ganache

It works also if you start hardhat node in another window, with the following definition in hardhat-config.js :

> networks: {
> hardhat: {
> initialBaseFeePerGas: 0,
> accounts: {
> mnemonic: "test test test test test test test test test test test junk",
> path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
> count: 10,
> accountsBalance: "100000000000000000000",
> },
> },
> }

> BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.
>
> Running 'scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py::main'...
> 25000000000000001
> The current entry fee is 25000000000000001
> Funding
> Transaction sent: >0xcd8f0db14647958c4902dcce05b2baf41f1a6604999867f4bd726df02273dc68
> Gas price: 2.0 gwei   Gas limit: 99258   Nonce: 5
> FundMe.fund confirmed   Block: 6   Gas used: 90235 (90.91%)
>
> Transaction sent: >0xab399fb117adac26e2a381e6fab907880a1bc796d64a26f6f7915925fd6b90d5
> Gas price: 2.0 gwei   Gas limit: 76963   Nonce: 6
> FundMe.withdraw confirmed   Block: 7   Gas used: 24967 (32.44%)

So it looks like a bug in Ganache GUI.